# Within Where Clause criteria like wildcarded function?

Tags: function, t-sql, where-clause, wildcard

Good afternoon all,

So this is my second question on the forum and I'm sure the number will increase as I am learning more about TSQL and its dynamic capabilities. If anyone can advice if I am using the best practice approach it would also be greatly appreciated.

This is a function I wrote to determine where the user is located:

```
    dbo.fnGetCOTLState(CURRENT_USER))
```

In one of the view I created, I have a where clause as follow:

```
    (dbo.OfficersT.ProcessState = dbo.fnGetCOTLState(CURRENT_USER))
```

Due to recent changes I need to update this to a to be more dynamic so I updated the = (equal) to a like as follow:

```
    (dbo.OfficersT.ProcessState LIKE dbo.fnGetCOTLState(CURRENT_USER))
```

However I realised that this is still not sufficient to extract the records I need, I must wild card the dbo.fnGetCOTLState function and coming from Microsoft access background I have tried the following syntax:

```
    (dbo.OfficersT.ProcessState LIKE '%' & dbo.fnGetCOTLState(CURRENT_USER)) & '%'

    (dbo.OfficersT.ProcessState LIKE %dbo.fnGetCOTLState(CURRENT_USER))%

    (dbo.OfficersT.ProcessState LIKE '%dbo.fnGetCOTLState(CURRENT_USER))%'
```

but none of them worked >_< It is highly probable that I am not using the correct words to google, but I can't seem to find anyone trying to use a wild card on a function anywhere! Not sure if it is even possible, but if anyone can offer some info for what I am trying to achieve, as usual I would be eternally grateful!!

SeanY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your attempts was close.  Change this:

```
(dbo.OfficersT.ProcessState LIKE '%' & dbo.fnGetCOTLState(CURRENT_USER)) & '%'
```

to this:

```
dbo.OfficersT.ProcessState LIKE '%' + dbo.fnGetCOTLState(CURRENT_USER) + '%'
```

The string concatenation operator in SQL Server is plus (`+`), not ampsersand.  Perhaps the confusion comes from your having a VBA background, where ampersand in fact is used for string concatenation.

Comment: I knew it had to be a syntax that I was missing! Learning TSQL is rather painful for me with all the VBA knowledge I am carrying ~_~ the fact that this knowledge is fairly niche doesn't help! Thank you very much for helping.. once again members of the stackoverflow has saved me from another few countless hours of headache!